# Access 2013 web app delete relationship

Tags: ms-access-2013

In an Access 2013 Web App, I created a relationship by changing a field type to "lookup" and set a related table/field. Now I want to remove the relationship. Whenever I try to change the field type to anything besides "lookup", it tells me I must delete the relationship in the Relationships menu, which doesn't exist in a Web App.

The MS support pages just link back and forth without ever answering this glaringly simple issue.

[MS Support Instructions for relationships in Access 2013 (not web apps)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-e9b56c50-6c3e-491d-949a-1313ffa29c1c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[How to create a relationship in an Access 2013 Web App (not delete it)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-relationship-40c998dd-4875-4da4-98c8-8ac8f109b85b#__create_a_relationship)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I agree that the message we display is a little misleading because the instructions only apply for Access desktop applications. I'll see if we can perhaps change that message. I think it is shared across desktop and web app but I'll ask around. I'll see if we can maybe update the help content articles too. I can't make promises of course, but I'll check on that too.

In any case, to delete an established relationship in an Access 2013 web app, you'll have to delete the lookup field itself. If you need to keep the existing data for some reason, you could temporarily create a new column in the table, use a data macro to copy all of the contents from the lookup field you want to delete into the temp column, and then delete the lookup field itself. You could then copy that data from the temporary column into a new column if need be.

I hope that helps.